# Self signed certificate issue in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, resttemplate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a self signed certificate for a website. I imported it into java cacert file using keytool. After that, it is working well with RestTemplate request.
When I use Apache HttpClients request I get an exception as below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:254)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:318)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at HttpClientRequestTest.test3(HttpClientRequestTest.java:93)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

RestTemplate code:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
final ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
```

Apache HttpClients example:

```
final HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
final HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Does anyone maybe have any idea why it is working with RestTemplate but not with HttpClients?
HttpClient version is 4.5.13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're dealing with *"any(!) sort of 'crypto issue,'"* you need to look at log files, *especially* "from the **server** side."

"The client," of course quite deliberately, "is supposed to learn absolutely nothing," because it is presumed that it is an "Eve-il intruder," not "Alice" or "Bob."  The client only perceives that the door has been slammed-shut in their face, entirely without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information to answer why.

What we do know is that it is the server that terminated the connection. Therefore, it seems that it is the client that's doing something wrong.

This is a good sign, as it means you can do something about it :)

You mention CA Certificates - I personally can't see a way for your server to care about the CA Certs you installed. These certificates are there to validate the certificate provided by the server.

You have a few options to figure it out:

A. Debug: Use a good de-compiler like the one that comes with IntelliJ. You will dig until the URL object type, you will see the certs provided, received... The encryption algorithm... Etc...
If you don't know for sure what any one of these things should be, at least compare it to a debug of the "one that works".

B. TCP trace. Depending on what you have available, you may be able to use WireShark to see the data. Some manual decryption may be necessary.
Again, compare to known-good values or at least to the method that works

C. Server logs. If you have access to those and they are good, the exception should surface into one of those logs and tell you what is wrong with the client message

D. Trial-and-Error. Try forgetting your assumptions and be more explicit with your configuration. It's possible something is being set to a default value and that isn't what the server likes